# Linux KDE system notification c++/Qt

Tags: c++, notifications, qt5, system-tray, kde-plasma

I'm developing app (plasmoid) for KDE Plasma 5 with c++ and QT. 
 What is simple way to emit system notification (notification in corner of screen like a notification for new email or disconnection from network)? I can do it from terminal by calling 'kdialog ...' but I don't know how to do it from c++ code and yeah I don't want to do 'system(kdialog ...)'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
QSystemTrayIcon* ic = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
ic->setVisible(true);
ic->showMessage(tr("Notify"), tr("Text"), QSystemTrayIcon::Information, 1000);
qApp->processEvents();
```